# Scatter plots with tree-structured nodes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

Trying to create plots of synthetic data like this (with Python, namely matplotlib and seaborn):

[image]

The blue dots can be done w/ ``, and maybe controlled with polar coordinates [like this example](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_scatter.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-polar-scatter-py). The red nodes are supposed to be a tree-structure, which I'm not sure how best to recreate.

Any suggestions or pointers to closely related examples? Thanks in advance!